# Pandas, round - function

Tags: pandas

Running the round - function on a pandas dataframe has no effect.

> 1. Why is that happening?
> 2. What would be the more general approach?

```
import pandas as pd
df_round=pd.DataFrame({'index': {0: 0.0, 1: 2.563624, 2: 5.127248, 3: 0.0},
 'time': {0: 10.254496, 1: 20.508992, 2: 15.381744, 3: 10.254496},
 'ph_1': {0: 7.690872, 1: 12.81812, 2: 20.508992, 3: 7.690872},
 'ph_2': {0: 17.945368, 1: 7.690872, 2: 20.508992, 3: 17.945368},
 'text': {0: 'foo', 1: 'bar', 2: 'spa', 3: 'm'}})

print("Before\n")
print(df_round)

decimals = pd.Series([1, 0, 2], index=['time','ph_1','ph_2'])
df_round=df_round.round(decimals)

print("After\n")
print(df_round)
```

Failure: The console prints out two times exactly the same.

Comment: variable added. Code is complete now

Comment: For me it working very nice.

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: yup for me also seems to work fine.

Comment: pd.__version__  '0.23.0'

Answer (score 0):

For me in last pandas version `0.23.4` it working nice, alternative solution is use `dictionary`:

```
df_round=df_round.round({'time':1,'ph_1':0,'ph_2':2})
print(df_round)
      index  time  ph_1   ph_2 text
0  0.000000  10.3   8.0  17.95  foo
1  2.563624  20.5  13.0   7.69  bar
2  5.127248  15.4  21.0  20.51  spa
3  0.000000  10.3   8.0  17.95    m
```

Comment: Looks like a problem in my environment. I'm using Spyder Py 3.6

Comment: @Impulsleistung - I use it too, under windows under python 3.6 and working nice.

Comment: I don't believe it: It's a Spyder problem! I retyped the code in a different context and it worked. That IDE is not only super slow but also buggy

Comment: @Impulsleistung - So do you start to use pycharm?